# How would you create a .gitignore in GitHub to ignore and remove .ipynb checkpoints?

Tags: github, terminal

Every time I try to use a ./sh command in the terminal, it creates a .ipynb checkpoint folder in github. Was thinking of adding a .gitignore file to remove .ipynb checkpoints. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Change directory (`cd`) into the local repository.
2. Edit with (`vi`/`vim`) the `.gitignore` file.
3. Add `**/*.ipynb_checkpoints/`.
4. Delete previous checkpoints.